# TableView populating rows, but not content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, ios10

I have a tableView currently that is being populated with content from a firebase database. I am able to print out the specific information that is to be populated in the cells, and the cells physically are being populated indicated by the ability to scroll the appropriate length of the populated data. I am not sure as to why it would be accessing the information and populating the cells, but not inserting the data into the cells?

**TableView:**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage

class Articles: UITableViewController {

var vcType:String = "Home"
//var valueTopass = [[String:String]]()
var rooms = [Room]()
var articleCell = ArticlesCell()

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.vcType == "Home"
    {
        self.rooms += ArticlesManager.sharedClient.rooms
    }
    else
    {
        if let obj = ArticlesManager.sharedClient.catRooms[self.vcType.lowercased()] //as? [Room]
        {
            self.rooms += obj
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()

    ArticlesManager.sharedClient.blockValueChangeInRoomArray = {
        newRoom in
        if self.vcType == "Home"
        {
            self.rooms.append(newRoom)
            self.rooms.sort(by: {
                if $0.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return false
                }
                if $1.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return true
                }

                return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
            })

        }
        else
        {
            if self.vcType.lowercased() == newRoom.category
            {
                self.rooms.append(newRoom)

                self.rooms.sort(by: {
                    if $0.created_Date == nil
                    {
                        return false
                    }
                    if $1.created_Date == nil
                    {
                        return true
                    }

                    return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
                })

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rooms.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "featured", for: indexPath) as! featuredCell
        let room = rooms[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell2.configureCell(room)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return cell2

    } else {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ArticlesCell
        let room = rooms[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
        cell.configureCell(room)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        return cell

    }   
}
}
```

**ArticleManager:**

```
import UIKit

class ArticlesManager: NSObject {

static let sharedClient = ArticlesManager()

var dateFormater:DateFormatter{
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z"
    return df
}

var roomsitems = ["Home", "News", "Features", "Opinion", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Editor"]

var rooms = [Room]()
var catRooms = [String:[Room]]()

var blockValueChangeInRoomArray:((Room) -> ())!

func fetchData()
{
    Data.dataService.fetchData {
        (room) in

        self.rooms.append(room)

        self.rooms.sort(by: {
            if $0.created_Date == nil
            {
                return false
            }
            if $1.created_Date == nil
            {
                return true
            }

            return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
        })

        if let obj = self.catRooms[room.category] //as? [Room]
        {
            var objRooms = obj
            objRooms.append(room)

            objRooms.sort(by: {
                if $0.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return false
                }
                if $1.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return true
                }

                return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending })

            self.catRooms[room.category] = objRooms
        }
        else
        {
            self.catRooms[room.category] = [room]
        }

        if self.blockValueChangeInRoomArray != nil
        {
            self.blockValueChangeInRoomArray(room)
        }
    }
}

}
```

**DataService:**

```
import UIKit

class ArticlesManager: NSObject {

static let sharedClient = ArticlesManager()

var dateFormater:DateFormatter{
    let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z"
    return df
}

var roomsitems = ["Home", "News", "Features", "Opinion", "Sports", "Entertainment", "Editor"]

var rooms = [Room]()
var catRooms = [String:[Room]]()

var blockValueChangeInRoomArray:((Room) -> ())!

func fetchData()
{
    Data.dataService.fetchData {
        (room) in

        self.rooms.append(room)

        self.rooms.sort(by: {
            if $0.created_Date == nil
            {
                return false
            }
            if $1.created_Date == nil
            {
                return true
            }

            return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending
        })

        if let obj = self.catRooms[room.category] //as? [Room]
        {
            var objRooms = obj
            objRooms.append(room)

            objRooms.sort(by: {
                if $0.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return false
                }
                if $1.created_Date == nil
                {
                    return true
                }

                return $0.created_Date.compare($1.created_Date) == ComparisonResult.orderedDescending })

            self.catRooms[room.category] = objRooms
        }
        else
        {
            self.catRooms[room.category] = [room]
        }

        if self.blockValueChangeInRoomArray != nil
        {
            self.blockValueChangeInRoomArray(room)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: NEVER call `reloadData` or any other table updating methods inside the `cellForRowAt` method. Bad, bad, bad. Take those calls out and see what happens.

Comment: Unrelated but why all the uses of `NSIndexPath`? Just use `IndexPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been able to figure out the particular issue that I was having. As I am using firebase, the rules as to who could "read" was, as default, set to authenticated users. In order to change this, you must go into the firebase console and either change it to public or authenticate users before loading the table view. Either way, I hope this was able to help you!

Answer (score 3):

Remove this line of code from `cellForRowAt indexPath` method:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

This is reloading Table continuously without giving it chance to *configureCell* and *display data*.